# awk starting from a fixed text, until the first blank line

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed

I'm trying to pipe into something that will return only the first "paragraph" or "section" separated by a blank line.  I thought I could use `awk` or `sed` to get a range as per some other answers but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$ cat txt
Package: plasma-desktop
Architecture: amd64
Version: 4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1
Supported: 3y

Package: plasma-desktop
Architecture: amd64
Version: 4:5.12.4-0ubuntu1
Supported: 3y

$ cat txt |awk '/^Package:/,/^$/'
Package: plasma-desktop
Architecture: amd64
Version: 4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1
Supported: 3y

Package: plasma-desktop
Architecture: amd64
Version: 4:5.12.4-0ubuntu1
Supported: 3y
```

Should it not return only the first "section"? (as per:
[Grep starting from a fixed text, until the first blank line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318595/grep-starting-from-a-fixed-text-until-the-first-blank-line)
and
https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/148692-awk-script-match-pattern-till-blank-line.html)

- If I use `grep -ve ^$` the blank lines get removed, so there's no special characters.
- If I try to extract a different part, I get the parts from both "sections":

  ```
  $ cat txt |awk '/^Package:/,/^Version:/'
  Package: plasma-desktop
  Architecture: amd64
  Version: 4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1
  Package: plasma-desktop
  Architecture: amd64
  Version: 4:5.12.4-0ubuntu1
  ```
- If I use `sed -n '/^Package:/,/^$/p'` or `sed -n '/^Package:/,/^Version:/p'` I get the same results as the equivalent awk.

How do I get `awk` or `sed` to stop after the first occurrence?

Comment: Welcome! Can you post the desired result? [edit] the question, don't add it in the comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is exactly why awk has a paragraph mode:

```
$ awk -v RS= 'NR==1' file
Package: plasma-desktop
Architecture: amd64
Version: 4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1
Supported: 3y
```

and to print the 2nd record is just the obvious change of `NR==1` to `NR==2`:

```
$ awk -v RS= 'NR==2' file
Package: plasma-desktop
Architecture: amd64
Version: 4:5.12.4-0ubuntu1
Supported: 3y
```

Never use range expressions btw - they make code for trivial problems very slightly briefer than using a flag but then if your requirements change in the slightest require a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions. So any time you thing you might want to use `/begin/,/end/` with sed or awk use `/begin/{f=1} f{print} /end/{f=0}` with awk instead and that gives you FAR more control on when/how to print the begin/end lines, etc.

Comment: Brilliant solution -- I never looked closely at RS before. Small extension -- if the file is big, then NR > 2 {exit} would speed things up.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant thanks. The performance enhancement to print one record would be `NR==1{print; exit}`.

Comment: Much better than my answer, I'm keeping it only to show what was wrong with the original approach.

Answer (score 2):

In `/begin/,/end/`, the "action flags" are turned on each time a `/begin/` match is found and are turned off when `/end/` match is found. The boundary lines with "begin" and "end" are also printed.

The consequences to your input are (printed lines have a comment after them on the below samples):

- With `'/^Package:/,/^$/'`:

```
    Package: plasma-desktop        #TURN ON
    Architecture: amd64            #
    Version: 4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1 #
    Supported: 3y                  #
                                   #TURN OFF
    Package: plasma-desktop        #TURN ON
    Architecture: amd64            #
    Version: 4:5.12.4-0ubuntu1     #
    Supported: 3y                  #
```

- With `'/^Package:/,/^Version:/'`:

```
    Package: plasma-desktop        #TURN ON
    Architecture: amd64            #
    Version: 4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1 #TURN OFF
    Supported: 3y

    Package: plasma-desktop        #TURN ON
    Architecture: amd64            #
    Version: 4:5.12.4-0ubuntu1     #TURN OFF
    Supported: 3y
```

To print only the paragraph starting from "Package:" you can write

```
sed -ne '/^$/q' -e '/^Package:/,$p' file
```

`sed` quits processing the file as soon as it finds a blank line because of `/^$/q`.

With `awk`:

```
awk '/^$/{exit};/^Package:/,0' file
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented by [Quasímodo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/388654/quas%C3%ADmodo)

> `/begin/,/end/` gets lines that match those regexes including the
>   boundary lines. begin turns on the printing, and end turns off. The
>   line right after your blank line turns on the printing again, because
>   it also has `Package:` in it.

I realized I can use `sed` and change the `/begin/` to `0` and it will start at the beginning.  Since there is only one beginning it will only match once.

```
$ cat txt |sed -n '0,/^$/p'
Package: plasma-desktop
Architecture: amd64
Version: 4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1
Supported: 3y
```