# grep, sed, awk, perl: Get section from a file based on ID inside the section

Tags: shell, text-processing

Assume I have a file in format:

```
(lots of sections...)

SECTION foo
    keyA=valA
    ...
ENDSECTION

(lots of sections...)
```

I could extract the section with sed using `sed -nE /^SECTION foo$/,/^ENDSECTION$/p`. My problem arises when the format changes to:

```
(lots of sections...)

SECTION
    keyA=valA
    id=foo
    ...
ENDSECTION

(lots of sections...)
```

Is there a way to get the section by using a one-liner with the common tools (grep, sed, awk, perl, bash)?

Comment: Are your sections always separated by blank lines?

Comment: Not necessarily, it's not file-specific but more of general question because I run into that kind of task quite often and usually hack my way around it.

Answer (score 1):

It somewhat depends on how "well-formed" your document is. If you are sure that every `SECTION` has a matching `ENDSECTION`, then the following `awk` code should work, although I wouldn't call it a "one-liner" (and I'm not sure that is possible in the first place).

```bsh
awk -v pat='id=foo' '/^SECTION/{n=f=0; delete buf;} \
 {buf[++n]=$0; if (index($0,pat)) f=1} \
 /^ENDSECTION/ {if (f) for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print buf[i]}' input.txt
```

- The search pattern will be whatever you assign `pat` (but in the current form, it only performs a fixed-string search, not a regexp-based one).
- When a line starting with `SECTION` (or whatever the keyword is) is found, a flag `f`(for "found") and a line counter `n` is initialized to zero. Also, since we need to buffer the entire section as the decision whether to print can only be made once the section is complete, we clear a buffer variable `buf`.
- For any line (including empty ones in this case), the line counter `n` is increased, and the line added to the array variable `buf`. If the pattern is found on the line, the `f` flag is set to `1`.
- If the `ENDSECTION` keyword is found at start of line, and the `f` flag is `1`, the buffer is printed line by line to output the relevant section.

If you could guarantee that all sections are separated by empty lines, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/578562/377345) could point you in the right direction on how to do it with less code, but if that is not guaranteed, the "paragraph mode" approach of `awk` will not work.

Also note that this suggestion is very much the bare minimum necessary to fulfill the task; if you want to skip empty lines or fulfill other sanity check requirements, the code quickly gets rather long.